# Grub won't install on Macbook Air 5,2 (13" 2012)

Tags: installation, grub2, macbook-air

I've run into a brick wall trying to get 12.04.1 LTS running on my new MacBook Air 5,2 (2012 13" model). The problem I keep getting is GRUB failing to install; here's the output from virtual terminal 4:

```
Sep  9 02:02:57 grub-installer: info: Installing grub on '/dev/sda5'
Sep  9 02:02:58 grub-installer: info: grub-install supports --no-floppy
Sep  9 02:02:58 grub-installer: info: Running chroot /target grub-install  --no-floppy --force "/dev/sda5"
Sep  9 02:02:58 grub-installer: /usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for /boot/grub (is /dev mounted?).
Sep  9 02:02:58 grub-installer: error: Running 'grub-install  --no-floppy --force "/dev/sda5"' failed.
```

I'm trying to dual-boot OS X and Ubuntu. I first resized the HFS+ partition in Disk Utility using OS X, then installed rEFIt, then dd'd the alternate-amd64+mac version of the disk image to a USB stick and booted off that. I'm also setting noapic before beginning the installation as recommended in [this forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2039799).

At first, following the advice in that post, I tried the daily image from cdimage.ubuntu.com/precise/daily/current/ and was getting an error message almost identical to the above. Then, hoping the release version would be more stable, I dd'd "ubuntu-12.04.1-alternate-amd64+mac.iso" from cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04/release/ to my USB stick instead. Same result.

/dev/sda5 is a 1.0 MB partition of type "Reserved BIOS boot area".

Googling the "cannot find a device for /boot/grub" error doesn't seem to turn up anything relevant to my situation.

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow the detailed instructions on Ubuntu's Apple Intel Installation [documentation page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation)?

According to that, you should be installing GRUB to Ubuntu's root partition (assuming the instructions are followed verbatim, that partition would be `/dev/sda3`, but your mileage may vary).

Comment: Oops, sorry I didn't notice this until now. I actually worked around this by installing Ubuntu 12.10 beta instead, which worked almost perfectly from the regular installer. Pretty sure I did what your link says, but it's now moot for me personally.